# WP Rest API - Post to ACF field?

Tags: java, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to post to my custom Wordpress field via the REST API from my android app. That said, when I look at the JSON structure of any ACF fields, they're nested inside "acf" like so:

```
{
  "acf": {
    "phone_number": "000-0000"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to post a phone number to the phone_number field at my endpoint with the following code/structure, but it won't seem to save?

```
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        String url = "http://myurl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/loggedinuser/36";

        String bearer = "Bearer ";

        MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
     
         JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {

            jsonObject.put("phone_number", "777-348-4349");
                
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonObject.toString());
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(mergeUrl)
                .method("POST", body)
                .addHeader("Accept-Charset", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Authorization", bearer + userToken)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();

        Response response = null;

        try {
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            String resStr = response.body().string();

            int responseCode = response.code();

            if (responseCode == 200) {


            } else {

            }

        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }}
```

I imagine it's because phone_number is nested inside of "acf". How can I write this line:

```
jsonObject.put("phone_number", "777-348-4349");
```

so that it matches the structure above? I can't seem to figure out how to nest phone_number inside of the acf value.

Comment: Can you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can nest it to match the structure:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {

    JSONObject acf = new JSONObject();
    acf.put("phone_number", "777-348-4349");
    jsonObject.put("acf", acf);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: Trying this now :) Will report back shortly!

Comment: Just tried this solution and the phone_number field on my Wordpress backend still remains empty :/ Which is strange because when I log jsonObject, it appears to be nested correctly.

Comment: Is your ACF field "shown in REST API"? Is the request correctly authenticated? Does it work when posting with Postman?

Answer (score 0):

Using ACF with the REST API is explained on [this page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/wp-rest-api-integration/). To sum it up:

- You need at least ACF version 5.11
- You need to enable the REST API for your field groups
- The endpoints for users are `/users/{user_id}` and `/users/me` (not `/users/loggedinuser/{user_id}`)
- The JSON structure is the following:

```js
{
    "acf":
    {
        "field": "Value"
    }
}
```